# Thread doesn't work as a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I've got some weird (or at least weird for me) problem with a thread. I've got main like this

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int port = 5555;
    String server = "127.0.0.1";
    int x=20, y=20, squareSize = 25;


    Thread connectionManager = new ConnectionManager(server, port, x, y);
    connectionManager.run();
    System.out.print("BUM");
```

where ConnectionManager is

```
public class ConnectionManager extends Thread{
private String server;
private int port;
private int x;
private int y; //dlugosc mapy

private Socket socket;
private int[][] currentMap;
File file;
PrintWriter printWriter;

public ConnectionManager(String server, int port, int x, int y) {
    this.server = server;
    this.port = port;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    currentMap = new int[x][y];

}

public int[][] getCurrentMap() {
    return currentMap;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    try {
        socket = new Socket(server, port);
        DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        while (true) {
            if (is.readBoolean() == true)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
                        currentMap[i][j] = is.readInt();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

But even though my connectionManager is a thread it doesn't go to the System.out.println unless the connection is closed from the server. I've been thinking about this for some time now and I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

Don't think that matters but main and connectionManager are in other maven modules (main is in a GUI module which has dependency on ConnectionManager's module)

I would appreciate any advises.

Comment: I can't believe that people are upvoting the classic start vs run mistake over and over again ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `connectionManager.run()` does not spawn the thread. It merely calls `run` and waits until it's done to reach the `System.out` line.

To run the `run` method in a separate thread, you'll need to call `connectionManager.start()`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start().

Comment: Thanks! Funny thing is that in a server project I did it run correctly (using      start() method) but here for some reason I did such a simple mistake.

Answer (score 5):

If you run the `run()` method directly, then you have not actually run it in a new thread.

To actually start a thread to do the task, you have to run its `start()` method. Under the hood, it creates a native thread and passes control to it, and that other thread is the one that runs the `run()` method.

Comment: Congrats for the 10k :)

Comment: Thanks! Funny thing is that in a server project I did it run correctly (using      start() method) but here for some reason I did such a simple mistake.